# How do I use Facebook's API to get all events that a set of users has been invited to?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Say I want to get all the events that Bob, Jane and Joe have been invited to. An event should only be returned if ALL THREE have been invited. What's the most efficient way to do this using Facebook's API? Obviously I could retrieve each user's events individually and then intersect them, but that seems slow.

Here's the relevant events table that can be queried using FQL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/

However, it seems FQL doesn't support INTERSECT, which would be helpful here?

Comment: FQL is not a full-fledged SQL dialect, but only a basic query language. It does not offer any kind of operator (that I know of) that would let you retrieve the info you want in one go; I’m afraid you have to do it yourself after getting the event info for each user separately.

Comment: Does FQL multiquery speed things up at all or is that just a convenient wrapper for functionality I could build myself (ie executing a bunch of queries in parallel)?

Comment: The main _speed_ advantage that FQL multiqueries (or Graph API batch requests) give you is that you have to make only _one_ HTTP request to the API, instead of several ones.

Comment: Hmm, does field expansion help at all? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/30/updates-to-the-graph-api/

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to get just the events where some group of users are members. It seems like the best you can do is get all the events each person is attending:

```
SELECT eid, uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE
   uid IN (BOB'S_UID, JANE'S_UID, JOE'S_UID)
```

The response will give you all events that any one of these people are attending. You'll need to loop through the response to find the events that all three people are attending.

I tried chaining together `uid [=/IN] n's_UID` statements with `AND`. That didn't work for a sample event that two of my friends were attending.